# When adding barlines in a music theory exam are all the bars supposed to be complete?

Tags: notation

Here are some samples I am working on. Either I have made a mistake or the final bar is incomplete. Is it normal in an exam to have incomplete bars at the end?

[image]

Comment: I hope the assignment makes extra clear that those are two separate examples. I can imagine plenty of students who would join the last beat of the top example and the first three beats of the second into a single measure, especially since doing so means ending with a full bar of the second excerpt.

Comment: yeah you have to just look at the letters on the left but it can be tricky

Comment: To stave off (heh) related questions about incomplete measures in "real" pieces: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/95245/did-the-music-of-the-common-practice-period-always-end-with-a-full-measure, https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/49445/is-a-rest-required-at-the-end-of-the-final-measure-of-a-piece/49455#49455

Comment: If it were one piece I would want to know how both the key signature and time signature change inside a measure.

Comment: @Richard - it does say '*extracts*', and they're written in different keys, and there wouldn't be a new (different) time sig. for what some may consider a follow on from the first extract - which then couldn't be starting on the 1st beat - as also stated. I think we're safe!

Answer (score 10):

Yes, they're literally open-ended. This means you can't necessarily work backwards, as sometimes that can help, so makes the question a touch more difficult.